# Картинка в statusbar и navigationbar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view

В приложении имеются разные экраны по цветам, а где-то ещё вверху находится картинка, можно ли как-то загнать картинку под статусбар как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали использовать Fullscreen Activity?

Comment: Это может решить проблему с statusbar. у вас нет мысли как быть с navigation, layout?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "navigation, layout". Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: Задумался когда писал, я имел ввиду navigationbar

Comment: Я не знаком с таким элементом, как navigationbar. Возможно, вы имеете в виду что-то вроде ActionBar, AppBar или Toolbar? Если нет, то прошу ссылочку на какое-нибудь описание этого элемента.

Comment: В любом случае могу предложить концепцию решения, где в FullscreenActivity на задний план ставится нужное изображение, а поверх него располагаются остальные элементы. Например Toolbar, а под ним контейнер фрагментов. В вашем случае Toolbar будет просто прозрачным